# Single choice role

Tags: discord, bots

How do I make single choice roles? I'll describe what I mean by that in some steps:

1. User enters discord server and gets a greeting message where he is asked to select a role
2. User goes to select a role and he has only 1 chance to choose his role
3. When a user choosed his role he can't choose any other role and he can't change his choosed role.

Is this possible and how do I make it?
My server uses sapphire bot at the moment. And has 3 roles.

I tried to do that in sapphire bot reaction role options, but it only allows 1 choice of role per user, but it allows the user to change his role after selection, which I don't want.

Comment: I think you should ask this question to the creator of the Saphir bot. StackOverflow is here to answer development questions, not Discord bot configurations.